# Nagios nrpe commands error out with asterisk

Tags: asterisk, nagios, nrpe

as the nrpe user when
Command: /scripts/nagisk.pl -c version 
Outputs: Asterisk 1.8.11-cert10

Using nrpe

Command: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H [HOSTNAME] -c check_asterisk_version

Outputs: Error getting version

I have this line in my nrpe.cfg

command[check_asterisk_version]=/scripts/nagisk.pl -c version2

Here is the script i am running
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagisk/

I also have simmaler issue's with different asterisk pluggin as well
http://www.it-slav.net/blogs/2009/02/13/asterisk-monitoring-with-nagios-or-op5-monitor/

Any Help would be greatly apriciated

Comment: I fiugred it out, my visudo had requiretty

Comment: You should post that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/323233/nrpe-unable-to-read-output-but-why/323236#323236