# NRPE error when using check_nrpe

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have 2 centos server

Server 1 - centos 6.8

Server 2 - centos 6.7

Originaly I had the issue on Server 1 but was able to fix the issue I had with the fix explained here

[NRPE unable to read output, but why?](https://serverfault.com/questions/323233/nrpe-unable-to-read-output-but-why)

When I try to the same fix on Server 2 i get the following error as explained in 
the above link.

```
root@server2 [/usr/local/nagios/libexec]# ./check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_exim
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

But if I run the command locally it works

```
root@server2 [/usr/local/nagios/libexec]#
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_exim_queue -c 20 -w 40 Mailqueue OK -
0 messages on queue
```

So to test I ran it as the user itself and it works

```
nagios@cloud-03 [/usr/local/nagios/libexec]# sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_exim_queue -c 20 -w 40
Mailqueue OK - 0 messages on queue
```

Any ideas will help

Comment: "*I ran it as the user itself ...*": no, you didn't.  The `sudo` invocation you show, shows it running as root (as no user is specified).  If you've become nagios, try just `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_exim_queue -c 20 -w 40`.

Comment: When running the command I get all is ok. But when I run `./check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_exim` i still het the error

Comment: "*When running the command I get all is ok*": would you mind showing us that command, running on the client, as the `nagios` user?  You haven't shown us that yet.  The output of `grep check_exim /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` from the client would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug in nrpe agent

From:https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf

How to go about debugging other problems...
When debugging problems it may be useful to edit the NRPE configuration file and change the debug=0 entry to
debug=1. Once you do that, restart the NRPE daemon if it is running as a standalone daemon. After you try using
the check_nrpe plugin again, you should be able to see some debugging information in the log files of the remote
host. Check your logs carefully – they should be able to help provide clues as to where the problem lies...

Comment: I have set the debugging to 1 but the only output I am getting is `Jul  6 14:41:16 server2 xinetd[1999]: START: nrpe pid=2183 from=::ffff:127.0.0.1
Jul  6 14:41:16 server2 nrpe[2183]: INFO: SSL/TLS initialized. All network traffic will be encrypted.
Jul  6 14:41:16 server2 xinetd[1999]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=2183 duration=0(sec)`

Comment: 1) Check your nrpe connection excluding the configuration of your command executing  "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1" shoud you give the NRPE version 2) Try to run the command ./check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_exim and check if the log in debug mode produce logs and report it here

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue. The problem was with the check_mailq plugin.
So after digging a bit and looking at it I was able to fix it.

The fix was adding the sudo command withing the script.

BEFORE

```
elsif ( $mailq eq "exim" ) {
        ## open mailq
        if ( defined $utils::PATH_TO_MAILQ && -x $utils::PATH_TO_MAILQ ) {
                if (! open (MAILQ, "$utils::PATH_TO_MAILQ | " ) )
```

After

```
elsif ( $mailq eq "exim" ) {
        ## open mailq
        if ( defined $utils::PATH_TO_MAILQ && -x $utils::PATH_TO_MAILQ ) {
                if (! open (MAILQ, "/usr/bin/sudo $utils::PATH_TO_MAILQ | " ) )
```

So after making that change

```
    root@server2 [/usr/local/nagios/libexec]# ./check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_exim    
OK: mailq (0) is below threshold (20/40)|unsent=0;20;40;0
```

Thanks for the help